# Dynamic colors for node bodies

Tags: 6, entities, theming

In Drupal 6, I have a CCK colorpicker field, and I would like to use the color for links, b/em tags, and headers in the body of the node.  In D7 i could use `drupal_add_css` to create inline CSS that is not aggregated, but that is not available in D6.  Is there a way of doing this that doesn't involve preprocessing the body and adding inline styles to the individual elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't done it to make inline CSS, but you could try creating a new region in your `.info`, and using [drupal_set_content](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_set_content/6) to add structured content.  You can then parse / format it in a [template_preprocess_page](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/6), and then print it in your `page.tpl.php`.  I've had to resort to similar tricks in the past to work around this.

I suspect your best place to call `drupal_set_content` from is a [hook_nodeapi(&$node, "view")](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6)